# Python loop dictionary items through a tkinter GUI using a button

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, checkbox, tkinter

I am currently making a menu test for my restaurant. I have made the GUI and am happy with its basic format (for now), but I am stuck on how to do my next step.

I have multiple checkboxes set up (different ingredients) and the plan is for different menu items to loop through (appear on the screen), the employee then checks the appropriate ingredients, clicks a submit and continue button that I have made and then the next menu item shows up in place of the previous one. There will be much more I have to do like reading and storing the input but for now I wanted to leap this hurdle before I moved on.

I am new with using Python for GUIs so I am not sure the best way to go about doing this.

I have found different code examples but nothing specific enough to implement into my program. Any advice is much appreciated!!

Here is a pic of my GUI:
[image: pic of gui]

```
from tkinter import *

globalvar = -1

class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, background="white")   
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("Wahoos Menu Test")

def main():
    def callBack(number):
        globalvar = number + 1
        item(globalvar)
    def item(number):
        menu = ['nft', 'nckt']
        m = Label(root, text=menu[number], fg="orange").grid(row=7, column=0)
    root = Tk()
    app = Example(root)
    #root.geometry("750x750+400+50")
    for r in range(20):
        for c in range(14):
            Label(root, text='',
                borderwidth=0).grid(row=r,column=c)

    B = Button(root, text ="Submit and Continue", relief=RIDGE, fg="black", command= lambda:callBack(globalvar)).grid(row=19, column=7)
    L = Label(root, text="What comes in the following", fg="blue").grid(row=6, column=0)
    #I = Label(root, text="***Loop Items Here***", fg="blue").grid(row=7, column=0)
    V = Label(root, text="Veggies", fg="green").grid(row=1, column=11, sticky=W)
    v1 = IntVar()
    Checkbutton(root, text="Lettuce", variable=v1, fg="black").grid(row=2, column=11, sticky=W)
    v2 = IntVar()
    Checkbutton(root, text="Cabbage", variable=v2).grid(row=3, column=11, sticky=W)
    v3 = IntVar()
    Checkbutton(root, text="Cheese", variable=v3).grid(row=4, column=11, sticky=W)
    v4 = IntVar()
    Checkbutton(root, text="Ahee Rice", variable=v4).grid(row=5, column=11, sticky=W)
    v5 = IntVar()
    Checkbutton(root, text="Brown Rice", variable=v5).grid(row=6, column=11, sticky=W)
    v6 = IntVar()
    Checkbutton(root, text="Banzai Veg", variable=v6).grid(row=7, column=11, sticky=W)
    v7 = IntVar()
    Checkbutton(root, text="Red Cabbage", variable=v7).grid(row=8, column=11, sticky=W)
    v8 = IntVar()
    Checkbutton(root, text="Black Beans", variable=v8).grid(row=9, column=11, sticky=W)
    v9 = IntVar()
    Checkbutton(root, text="Cajun White Beans", variable=v9).grid(row=10, column=11, sticky=W)
    T = Label(root, text="Tortillas     ", fg="green").grid(row=1, column=12, sticky=W)
    t1 = IntVar()
    Checkbutton(root, text="Corn          ", variable=t1).grid(row=2, column=12, sticky=W)
    t2 = IntVar()
    Checkbutton(root, text="Flour", variable=t2).grid(row=3, column=12, sticky=W)
    P = Label(root, text="Proteins", fg="green").grid(row=1, column=13, sticky=W)
    p1 = IntVar()
    Checkbutton(root, text="Carne Asada", variable=p1).grid(row=2, column=13, sticky=W)
    p2 = IntVar()
    Checkbutton(root, text="Flamebroiled Chicken", variable=p2).grid(row=3, column=13, sticky=W)
    p3 = IntVar()
    Checkbutton(root, text="Blackened Chicken", variable=p3).grid(row=4, column=13, sticky=W)
    p4 = IntVar()
    Checkbutton(root, text="Flamebroiled Fish", variable=p4).grid(row=5, column=13, sticky=W)
    p5 = IntVar()
    Checkbutton(root, text="Pork", variable=p5).grid(row=6, column=13, sticky=W)
    p6 = IntVar()
    Checkbutton(root, text="Shrimp", variable=p6).grid(row=7, column=13, sticky=W)
    p7 = IntVar()
    Checkbutton(root, text="Tofu", variable=p7).grid(row=8, column=13, sticky=W)
    p8 = IntVar()
    Checkbutton(root, text="Blackened Mushroom", variable=p8).grid(row=9, column=13, sticky=W)
    p9 = IntVar()
    Checkbutton(root, text="Rice and Beans", variable=p9).grid(row=10, column=13, sticky=W)
    p10 = IntVar()
    Checkbutton(root, text="Banzai Veg", variable=p10).grid(row=11, column=13, sticky=W)
    S = Label(root, text="Sauces", fg="green").grid(row=1, column=14, sticky=W)
    s1 = IntVar()
    Checkbutton(root, text="Salsa", variable=s1).grid(row=2, column=14, sticky=W)
    s2 = IntVar()
    Checkbutton(root, text="Guacamole", variable=s2).grid(row=3, column=14, sticky=W)
    s3 = IntVar()
    Checkbutton(root, text="Sour Cream", variable=s3).grid(row=4, column=14, sticky=W)
    s4 = IntVar()
    Checkbutton(root, text="Roasted Pepper", variable=s4).grid(row=5, column=14, sticky=W)
    s5 = IntVar()
    Checkbutton(root, text="Ketchup", variable=s5).grid(row=6, column=14, sticky=W)
    s6 = IntVar()
    Checkbutton(root, text="Ranch", variable=s6).grid(row=7, column=14, sticky=W)
    s7 = IntVar()
    Checkbutton(root, text="Balsamic", variable=s7).grid(row=8, column=14, sticky=W)
    s8 = IntVar()
    Checkbutton(root, text="Mr. Lees", variable=s8).grid(row=9, column=14, sticky=W)
    s9 = IntVar()
    Checkbutton(root, text="Teriyaki", variable=s9).grid(row=10, column=14, sticky=W)
    s10 = IntVar()
    Checkbutton(root, text="Tapatio", variable=s10).grid(row=11, column=14, sticky=W)
    s11 = IntVar()
    Checkbutton(root, text="Cream Cheese", variable=s11).grid(row=12, column=14, sticky=W)
    s12 = IntVar()
    Checkbutton(root, text="Aoli", variable=s12).grid(row=13, column=14, sticky=W)

    root.bind('<Return>', callBack)
    root.mainloop()  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Could you upload your picture to a free image hosting site (ie imgur.com) then update your question? At the moment your question is quite vague and it's hard to understand what you're asking.

Comment: Hey thanks for the site, here is a pic of my current GUI, I hope this helps explain a little bit, if there is any other clarification you would like please let me know!  http://imgur.com/GgPCz

Comment: I'm still a bit unclear, will your program will be used to test employees knowledge of the menu? Ie choose the ingredients that go into recipe A,B,C etc then they get a grade at the end?

Comment: Yes as the menu items loop through the new employees will check the appropriate check boxes then submit/continue until all questions have been answered at which time a grade will be produced.  For now I am just trying to get the code to change the menu item each time the button is pressed.  Right now it starts blank then after the first click the first item in the list appears but then it is stuck to that one, does not go on to the next one after more clicks.  I think it has to do with my variable declaration placement>?

Comment: here I added some code I have been playing with, maybe this will help.  I really appreciate you trying to help me!

Answer (score 2):

In your callBack method, `globalvar = number + 1` does not update the value of the global variable `globalvar`, it creates a new local variable called `globalvar`. If you want the globalvar variable to be altered, you have to add `global globalvar` in your method to explicitly refer to your global variable.

```
def callBack(number):
    global globalvar
    globalvar = number + 1
    item(globalvar)
```

Note that using such a global variable, you do not need to have the value passed as a parameter and could just use `Button(...,command=callBack)`

Other remarks:

- with the grid geometry manager, you do not have to create the 20x14 "empty label" table (removing this loop will not change anything)
- in `item` method, instead of creating a Label, you could update the text of the existing one (it implies (1) holding a reference to the label in a variable (2) call `config(text="new text")` on this reference). Creating new labels will reveal hazardous when replacing a label by a shorter (you are now just stacking them on top of others)
- when you initialize B, L, I, V, you do not store anything in the variable. You store the answer of the call to `grid` (which is always None). To keep a reference on items you have to split your code in two lines :

```
L = Label(root, text="What comes in the following", fg="blue")
L.grid(row=6, column=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

So, what exactly is the problem? The title mentions looping through a dictionary. Tkinter is no different than any other library - you can do looping like you do for anything else.

For example:

```
for thing in ("Lettuce", "Cabbage", "Cheese"):
    var[thing] = IntVar()
    cb[thing] = Checkbutton(root, text=thing, variable=var[thing], ...)
    cb[thing].grid(...)
```

Is there something more you were looking for?

Comment: Yeah, I know I said dictionary and my code is using a list but adding the buttons isn't my issue, the problem I am having is changing the "menu item" each time the "submit and continue" button is clicked.  As of now, the area starts out blank, after i click the button once "nft" pops up in the appropriate area, but then no matter how many time I click it, it never moves on to the next one..

Comment: @crenfro: It's really hard to undertand wha you are trying to do. When things like this don't work, pdb is your friend. That, or a strategically placed print statement. Just follow the logic of your code. At some point you will discover that a variable doesn't have the value you think it has. I've also got to say... It's very unusual to pass a global variable to a callback, and then set that very same global. Your intent is very unclear.

Comment: No problem. to me its a clear question but yeah, everyone I've talked to seems very unclear as to what exactly I am trying to do so for now I will keep on the trial and error path and maybe define a more concise question.  Thanks for your help I do appreciate it.